# Insert remote script and execute it

Tags: javascript

I know - by trying - that using createElement or appendChild, that script tags are executed when they are added to the DOM.

My question is: how many more methods are there available to add a script tag to the DOM and execute it after?

I've seen that insertAdjacentHTML doesn't execute javascript.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is, do you really need to add additional JavaScript file after the html has been loaded?

Comment: @MatusDubrava In this case, its related with advertising (out-of-page creatives), so, in short, yes.